# How to get the total of a database column

Tags: php

I have a column of data returned from my database and I'd like to know how to get the sum for the entire column. Can someone tell me if there is a built in function for this?

```
123.00
12.00
1.00
-----
136.00 < this is what I need.
```

Please see the accompanying post for the mysql portion of my code.
[How to get the total sum for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802244/how-to-get-the-total-sum-for-a-column)

Comment: No, I'm returning several columns of data and need to get the sum of the column. I can get the total of the row but that isn't what I need. I need the column total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) you can return all this values in a `sum()` function, If important to you also all values and the total amount

if you store this in array
in php u can [use](http://php.net/array_sum) `array_sum`

Comment: Thanks Haim for the tip. I'll look into it now.

Comment: +1 As this is the same as @Harish's answer, but this was here long before.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the aggregate functions of your database SQL; something like `SELECT SUM(column) FROM table;`.  This way you leave the data on the database server, saving bandwidth and php-computational resources.

Comment: I can't. I'm already returning numerous columns of data and there is no way, that I know of to sum the columns. Please have a look at the other question I posted in the mysql section.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean ?
if you want to get sum through query

Go for `SUM()` in query using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT SUM(`price`) FROM TABLE GROUP BY `item`;
```

or

use

```
array_sum() in php
```

Comment: I think array_sum may be what I need. THanks Harish.

Comment: I ALWAYS vote the correct answer. I must wait 1 more minute before I can accept it.